# Alleged missing character in IBM Plex

Tags: fonts, unicode

I'm having an issue getting some special characters to work when using LuaLaTeX and the IBM Plex fonts. Here's a minimal example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{plex-serif}
\usepackage{plex-sans}
\usepackage{plex-mono}

\begin{document}

Here's a τ, \texttt{and here's a monospace τ}.

\end{document}
```

Compiling this with LuaLaTeX from an up-to-date TeX Live 2023 creates some warnings:

```
Missing character: There is no τ (U+03C4) in font [IBMPlexSerif-Regular.otf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;!
Missing character: There is no τ (U+03C4) in font [IBMPlexMono-Regular.otf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig;!
```

And indeed, the rendering confirms something is wrong:

[image: screenshot of the rendering, with all τs rendering as]

I don't get why. The IBM Plex fonts should contain the τ symbol, at least they seem to when I use them in other applications. I tried using `fontspec` to access by system-installed version of the font instead, but this made no difference, so I suspect something else is broken.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: In my test only the monospaced one is missing.

Comment: For me they are both missing. The font seems complete for Latin and Cyrillic but for Greek only a few math letters are defined, and not τ.

Comment: Regarding the other applications: most likely they use a fallback font, i.e., if the selected font does not contain the character they take it from some default font that may or may not look similar. For LuaLaTeX you can do the same if you like (take the τ from DejaVu or something).

Comment: See for example https://fonts.google.com/specimen/IBM+Plex+Serif/glyphs that shows there is no Greek in the font.

Comment: I get it in ibm plex sans, but not in serif or mono. As said before, the tau (U+03C4) is simply not there.

Comment: Thank you all. Indeed, it looks like I got tricked with an automatic fallback, I'll look into setting up a fallback in LaTeX.